# What Redemption MAPITag does the RDORecipient.MessageResponseStatus property map to?

Tags: outlook-redemption

In Redemption, I can query the recipients collection for each appointment and fetch the MessageResponseStatus to see if the recipient has accepted or declined the meeting.  I am working on changing our implementation to use the MAPITable functionality in Redemption, but I need the MAPITag for that property.  However, I can't find one that looks right.

Which MAPITag property should I request to get that value?

I tagged CDO because MessageResponseStatus is a CDO property under the covers, but must map to a MAPI field down deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  Looks like `PR_RECIPIENT_TRACKSTATUS (0x5FFF0003)` is the MAPITag I was looking for.